# Polymer web-component-tester / selenium is stalling

Tags: selenium, polymer, web-component-tester

We are trying to run the web-component-tester however it keeps stalling on the Selenium step.

When I run `wct -l chrome --verbose`

I get the following

```
hook: prepare
hook: prepare:selenium
hook done: prepare:selenium
Starting Selenium server for local browsers
11:47:46.357 INFO - Launching a standalone server
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web-component-tester\node_modules\wct-local\node_modules\selenium-standalone\.selenium\chromedriver\2.13-x64-chromedriver
Setting system property webdriver.ie.driver to C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web-component-tester\node_modules\wct-local\node_modules\selenium-standalone\.selenium\iedriver\2.44.0-x64-IEDriverServer.exe
11:47:46.809 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.31-b07
11:47:46.809 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 x86
11:47:46.872 INFO - v2.44.0, with Core v2.44.0. Built from revision 76d78cf
11:47:47.669 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:11655/wd/hub
11:47:47.669 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
11:47:47.685 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
11:47:47.919 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@3c1e69
11:47:47.919 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
11:47:47.919 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
11:47:47.919 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
11:47:47.935 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:11655
11:47:47.935 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@11bc7ed
```

Then after a few minutes of stalling it follows up with

```
hook done: prepare with error: [Error: Unable to connect to selenium]
Error: Unable to connect to selenium
```

Running these same tests from the browser works without a problem.

While it has hanged, we can still connect via browser to http://127.0.0.1:11655/wd/hub

I've tried Googling but not a lot of luck.

What are the things that could go wrong or how can I debug this further?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the node modules doesn't use the Internet Explorer proxy values.

In your environment variables, create a new one

- Name  : no_proxy
- Value : localhost, 127.0.0.1

Don't forget to restart your shell session after applying

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was due to the proxy setting of my org. When i went out of my org's network and connected through internet, i was able to run the tests through selenium. I have not yet able to find a way through the proxy settings as of now. I was running on mac. You might need to try through normal internet setup and check.